# How to write FILE_FORMAT in Snowflake to Java code?

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, file-format

I am trying to execute COPY INTO statement in Java code like this:

```
copy into s3://snowflake
  from "TEST"."PUBLIC"."USER_TABLE_TEMP"
  storage_integration = s3_int
  file_format = CSV_TEST;
```

And it works fine.

Is there any way to add this `file_format` in Java code, so there is no need to set it up in Snowflake?

For example, SQL code of `file_format` that I have set in Snowflake is

```
ALTER FILE FORMAT "TEST"."PUBLIC".CSV_TEST SET COMPRESSION = 'NONE' FIELD_DELIMITER =
     ',' RECORD_DELIMITER = '\n' SKIP_HEADER = 0 FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = 'NONE' 
    TRIM_SPACE = TRUE ERROR_ON_COLUMN_COUNT_MISMATCH = FALSE ESCAPE = 'NONE' 
    ESCAPE_UNENCLOSED_FIELD = '\134' DATE_FORMAT = 'AUTO' TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'AUTO' NULL_IF = ('\\N');
```

Is there any way to write this as Java code?

**UPDATE**

Here is the code where I am using copy into statement:

```
String q = "COPY INTO s3://snowflake/"+ userId +" from \"EPICEROS\".\"PUBLIC\".\"USER_TABLE_TEMP\" storage_integration = s3_int file_format = CSV_TEST OVERWRITE=TRUE;";

jdbcTemplatePerBrand.get(brand).query(q, s -> {});
```

So how can I apply like file_format created on execution of query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution that I found for my question.

To be able to write `file_format` from code and not create one in Snowflake I did like this:

```
copy into s3://snowflake
  from "TEST"."PUBLIC"."USER_TABLE_TEMP"
  storage_integration = s3_int
  OVERWRITE = TRUE
  file_format = (type = csv compression = 'none' file_extension ='csv'  
  FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = '"'
  NULL_IF = ()
  single = true
  max_file_size = 4900000000;
```

I also added `OVERWRITE = TRUE` which means that if my file exists alredy in S3, overwrite it with new one.

`single = true` and `max_file_size = 4900000000` means that I am allowing to export files big to 5 GB. If I haven't added these two, my one big file would be separated in few smaller `.csv` files, which I did not want.

Answer (score 2):

You are wanting an [EXTERNAL STAGE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-stage.html)

Which you would create like:

```
CREATE STAGE awesome_stange_name
    URL = 's3://snowflake'
    FILE_FORMAT = test.public.csv_test
```

and then you can copy to it:

```
COPY INTO @awesome_stange_name
  FROM test.public.user_table_temp;
```

This means if the user doing the copy has permission to use the stage, then they can, without need to have access to the security tokens needed to working with that secure location.

Comment: But with this I still need to set `FILE_FORMAT = test.public.csv_test`? So, I should still set csv_test inside Snowflake?

Comment: again the "file format" is like the "stage" it is a thing you need to refer to, but you don't need to spell the whole thing out every time, thus it still add a large amount of value, imho

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to write this as Java code?

In Snowflake, creating and altering file formats is done through SQL. You can simply execute a SQL statement through a JDBC connection in Java.

Just change your alter to a create if the file format is not already created:

```
CREATE FILE FORMAT "TEST"."PUBLIC".CSV_TEST COMPRESSION = 'NONE' FIELD_DELIMITER =
     ',' RECORD_DELIMITER = '\n' SKIP_HEADER = 0 FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = 'NONE' 
    TRIM_SPACE = TRUE ERROR_ON_COLUMN_COUNT_MISMATCH = FALSE ESCAPE = 'NONE' 
    ESCAPE_UNENCLOSED_FIELD = '\134' DATE_FORMAT = 'AUTO' TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'AUTO' NULL_IF = ('\\N');
```

Assign that to a String variable like `sql` and just run it like any other statement using JDBC:

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
```

You can then have a line `rs.next();` and read from the first ordinal column or the column name `status` (in lowercase) to get the success/failure message.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I think this is exactly what I am looking for. I updated my question with query that I am using. Can you please give example of how would u use this ResultSet in my query? Thank you!